# Cassandra integration testing in Java 17

Tags: java, cassandra, integration-testing

How do you write integration tests for Cassandra in Java 17? I tried using cassandra-unit but had no success with it since seems like this project is dead and has the lack of Java 17 support. Can't use testcontainers because of some specificity of CI environment in my company. Any other options?

Thanks in advance.